# Reading the IMG within an A on click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to adapt my script to read the alt attribute of an img within an a.

For some reason, this isn't work:

```
$("#thumbs a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var title = $(this + " img").attr("alt");
    alert(title);
});
```

It returns a value of `[object Object]`.

I'd appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this + " img")` will not select anything so the alert which you are seeing is just an empty jQuery object. You should using `$(this).find("img")` which will select all the `img` elements within `this` i.e the anchor element in this case.

```
$("#thumbs a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var title = $(this).find("img").attr("alt");
    alert(title);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I'll accept as soon as it lets me. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your selector to use the second parameter, which is the context in which to evaluate the selector.

```
$("#thumbs a").click(function(event) {
    var title = $('img', $(this)).attr("alt");
    alert(title);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/q4Bsq/2/

Comment: Ah, I know this would make sense, but I prefer the other method, so +1.